# Deployment of spring boot app failing on tomcat v 8.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I have application developed in spring boot (v 1.5.9.RELEASE) which is working with tomcat v 7.0

I need to upgrade to new version of tomcat v 8.5. I have installed it ( apache-tomcat-8.5.32) and tried to deploy the same app. But I am getting exception while deployment of app.

Exception is with slf4j and log4j multiple bindings. I have started development of my app with Spring Initializr tool (https://start.spring.io/)

How can I fix this issue? As I am not aware of which specific dependency causing this issue and where do I need to add exclusion. Please help with this.

Comment: Are you not using Spring Boot's own Tomcat instance? Are you converting to a .war file and then deploying to Tomcat in the traditional sense?

Comment: Agree with @HomerPlata, you can just use the embedded server https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html.

Comment: You didn't show us your code nor error you are getting. Sorry but in such case it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete post.
Here is error which I am getting: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
 at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54)

Answer (score 1):

Well, AFAIK Spring Boot uses Logback by default rather than SLF4J. So I suspect that's where the multiple bindings issue comes from ([documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings)).

Your logging should contain a message mentioning what bindings clash, you can use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where it comes from. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962453/2678078) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19656906/2678078) answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will check