# JAVA SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings on debug

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, slf4j

I'm building a Java API and this happens on my vsCode when I try to debug my main class :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/CDINDELE/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

I know this is a exclusion issue, so I've excluded the `slf4j` from my dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<exclusions>
     <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-over-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

It works well with `mvn` install, and my API is working great with

```
java -jar myWar
```

However when I'm trying to use the debug with vscode on my main class (using the java plugin) the issue is coming back so it's impossible for me to debug this app which is not very convenient.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656496/multiple-slf4j-bindings-cause-error?rq=1

Comment: @Killer As I said, It works great when I'm building the war, so it should be good, it's not working when I'm debugging the app

Comment: Could you try to clear `.m2` folder or simply just libs in `vscode`? But for safety put `.m2` folder into a zip archive. 

Also as an alternative way you can try to do the same with another IDE as an `Intellij IDEA` and check the difference and result of it.

Comment: Or try to print the maven dependency tree this should show you all the bindings and help you resolve the issue.